DAX add column to table with true or false on based used filter
I have an independent table with two columns (dates and years). On the dates column I put in a slicer for users. I want to add a column to another table that will be true if user filtered dates within the range or false if the period otherwise.
CREATE TABLE
(filter) Smart period = 
CALENDAR(
    MIN('(dim) Calendar'[Date]),
    MAX('(dim) Calendar'[Date])
)

ADD COLUMN
Year = YEAR('(filter) Smart period'[Date])

ADD COLUMN ON ANOTHER TABLE
IsSmartPeriod = 
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ('(filter) Smart period'[Year]),
    TRUE (),
    FALSE ()
)

But it did not work for me, i always get false. I suspect something might be wrong with HASONEVALUE().
I have several values in '(filter) Smart period'[Year] but one unique, then i try using

IF(DISTINCTCOUNT('(filter) Smart period'[Year]) = 1,....
no it no worked.


SELECTETVALUE('(filter) Smart period'[Year], 2024)
No it does not work too, and i can't state definite year!

Please help me, what Do I need to use? Solving this example will help me put two period label in matrix columns.
Like that (There is only one period in the selection)
My example

I think you can build relationship between tables, then the date selection on the date table will affect the other table. Or you need to use DAX to create measure to control the output.The screenshot you provided contains two different date period. Could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?

Ryan thank you for your response.  I explored several another DAX's questions, and i got an understanding what it is not possible to create a column or table based on a user's choice date range from another table. I think me will need  build measures with offset range of dates from user range and output name of period above the matrix's layer (not in columns matrix) in another measures. Or using parameter fields and build one measure which check them and output different values.  In work....
